# How to identify three business days from, and including, today into the past and future (excluding weekends) and put them into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, dataframe

How would I identify three business days from, and including, today into the past and future (excluding weekends) and put them into a dataframe?

**Example:**
Today is Friday, 01/13/2017

I want to count +/- 3 business days and put them into a dataframe

**Expected Output:**

```
       A
0 01/10/2017
1 01/11/2017
2 01/12/2017
3 01/13/2017
4 01/17/2017
5 01/18/2017
6 01/19/2017
```

I experiemented with this, but I can't quite get what I need:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay 

today = date.today()
plustwo = today + timedelta(days=3)
minustwo = today - timedelta(days=3)
caldr = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
df = pd.date_range(minustwo,plustwo,freq=caldr)
```

**Current Output:**

```
>>> df
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-10', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```

**Solution:**

```
>>> pd.date_range(start=today - pd.offsets.BusinessDay(3), end=today + pd.offsets.BusinessDay(3), freq='B')

DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-10', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13',
               '2017-01-16', '2017-01-17', '2017-01-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Comment: The output that you get is indeed correct for `USFederalHolidayCalendar`. This has all the weekdays barring Sat/Sun. Do `caldr.weekmask` to check this and `caldr.holidays` to get it's list of all holiday dates. Incidentally, 16th falls in this list. So, the working business days you get is actually the correct one for this calender selection.

Comment: Since the date_range extends to a new week, shouldn't the 16th-18th also be included, since they are Mon, Tue, Wed?  This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: No, `pd.date_range` first sets it's range of dates to operate at. Here, it starts at `'2017-01-10'` and settles down at `'2017-01-16'`. Then, the frequency part actually comes into play. So, it rightly detects `'2017-01-10'` upto `'2017-01-13'`. Then, comes your Sat/Sun and `'2017-01-16'` part which is by default a holiday as per it's rule of functioning.

Comment: What would I need to change in my code to get the expected output?  That would help me understand what's going on.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use the Business day frequency, `"B"` and then you could offset these by the number of Sat/Sun days that fall in between them. Here, it would be 2 days more if you do not want to alter the `start` and `end` dates.

Comment: I forgot about Martin Luther King day on Monday, 16th, so I will need to modify my question.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to always grab +/- 3 business days regardless of the day of the week.

Comment: I'm going to extend the range and then just count the first three days on either side of "today" and that should do it.  Thank you!

Comment: If business days are of interest to you, then `pd.date_range(start=today - pd.offsets.BusinessDay(3), end=today + pd.offsets.BusinessDay(3), freq='B')` would give you +/- 3 business working days starting from today's date.

Comment: omg.. that was it! Thank you!!

Comment: post your own solution instead of adding it to your question so that it benefits everyone, thanks

Comment: @NickilMaveli, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @MaxU, Yup, it's added.

Comment: @Mike, I've written the answer. You could accept it if that worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the required offsets to the `start` and `end` args of `pd.date_range` so that the dates appear within +/- tolerance of that specified amount (Here *3 business days*).

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessDay

delta = BusinessDay(3)        # offset to +/- 3 days
today = date.today()          # datetime.date(2017, 1, 14)
pd.date_range(start=today-delta, end=today+delta, freq='B')
```

produces:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-11', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13', '2017-01-16',
               '2017-01-17', '2017-01-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```